# expandable list not scrolling

Tags: listview, expandable

hy, i have an expandable list on a scrolling view.The view is scrolling , but my expandable list is not scrolling. any advice, please?
this is the code for list.I also set the scrollable property of the list in properties to true, but no result? the items in the list are clickable and they respond to click, but the list is still not scrooling.Please advice..

```
     ExpandableListView listview= (ExpandableListView)        findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);

 GundamExpAdapter gea = new GundamExpAdapter(this);

        ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<String>();
        models.add("Turn on silent profile");
        models.add("Turn off silent profile");
        models.add("Turn on wifi");
        models.add("Turn off wifi");
        models.add("Turn on gps");
        models.add("Turn off gps");
            gea.AddGroup("Functionalities", models);
        listview.setAdapter(gea);
        //ExpandableListView elv = getExpandableListView();
        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listview.setEnabled(true);
```

and this is the adapter for my list:

```
      public class GundamExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
   {
    /*-------------------------- Fields --------------------------*/

    private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> myData = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    private final HashMap<Integer, String> lookUp = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private final Context context;

    public  class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;


    }


    /*-------------------------- Public --------------------------*/

    public GundamExpAdapter(final Context con)
    {
        context = con;
    }

    public boolean AddGroup(final String groupName, final ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        final ArrayList<String> prev = myData.put(groupName, list);

        if (prev != null)
            return false;

        lookUp.put(myData.size() - 1, groupName);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {
        if (lookUp.containsKey(groupPos))
        {
            final String str = lookUp.get(groupPos);
            final ArrayList<String> data = myData.get(str);

            return data.get(childPos);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {  
        return 0;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean isLastChild, 
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

         if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1row);
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPos, childPos).toString());
            textView.setTypeface(font);
            return convertView;

    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) 
    {
        if (lookUp.containsKey(groupPos))
            return myData.get(lookUp.get(groupPos)).size();

        return 0;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPos) 
    {
        if (lookUp.containsKey(groupPos))
            return myData.get(lookUp.get(groupPos));

        return null;
    }

    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return myData.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
         ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater    infalInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null,
                            false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView1row);
                    //Log.d("heading", getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
                    holder.textView.setText("Functionalities");
                    holder.textView.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.textView.setTypeface(font);
                    holder.textView.setTextSize(22);
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(android.R.color.darker_gray);


            }

        return convertView;

    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {
        return true;
    }






}
enter code here
```